# Are there valid implementations of the Sync trait apart from the Rust standard library?

Tags: rust

`Sync` and `Send` are part of the language. `Arc` and `Mutex` are part of the standard library and both implement `Send` and `Sync`. Are there structures  apart from the standard library (`std::sync`) (e.g in some crates) that do something like `unsafe impl Sync for SomeStruct {}` for valid reasons? In my humble understanding no developer will ever need implementations of `Sync` except the ones developing the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`crossbeam`](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam), a crate which provides "tools for concurrent programming in Rust", for example has an [`unsafe impl Sync for AtomicCell`](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/blob/7e2e2a67e8231c93a2dcaf95a15406babae31ccf/crossbeam-utils/src/atomic/atomic_cell.rs#L38).

Comment: Alright! So if I get it right, when I develope "regular" multithreaded applications normally I never have to implement the Sync trait myself and instead just use std and appropriate crates.

Comment: @phip1611 No. If you are developing primitives that require extensive parts of their functionality to be `unsafe` to guarantee something (as is the case of `AtomicCell` for `crossbeam`, which is a great example of this), you will sometimes have the possibility to do so. It comes with the caveat of *having to prove* and **be certain** that your entity is actually `Send` (or `Sync`).

Comment: The `unsafe impl` really gives off the idea well - these implementations of marker traits are left purely for cases where the compiler (and/or borrow checker) cannot infer that your types are `Send` or `Sync` even though you know they are.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I think the key point in the comment was "application". Most "applications" won't need to manually implement something like that. If you're building concurrency primitives that's different obviously.